# Android - Google Drive - Can't get results from the query

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using following tutorial
https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/android/queries?hl=fr-FR

in that, it has following code

```
Query query = ...;
Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query)
        .setResultCallback(new OnChildrenRetrievedCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onChildrenRetrieved(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        // Iterate over the matching Metadata instances in mdResultSet
    }
});
```

But I can't find OnChildrenRetrievedCallback() method. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to retrieve the results of the query and iterate through them:

```
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
            .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
            return;
        }
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
        mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
    }
};
```

OnChildrenRetrievedCallback() class had been removed in Drive 4.X update.
You can still view the [old sample implementation](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/ab1f3a0f2773c1399a34019298522702e659f3e1/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CheckFileSyncStatusActivity.java) in Google's github. The change was made in [this commit](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/commit/92f0c1b02d2c428881b9815e9f73335d3d7b64c2). The above implementation can be found in [this page](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/QueryFilesActivity.java).

Comment: A half of a year has past, but https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries still offers to use onChildrenRetrieved. Thanks, @Rivero. Though a [ListFilesActivity](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesActivity.java) contains a variant with onResult.